# Cursor spinning endlessly while installing ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04

I am new to Linux and trying to install ubuntu 20.04 LTS, at the step of updates and other software,. When I click continue then cursor spins endlessly.
[image: screenshot of my screen]

My system configuration screenshot is attached
[image: screenshot]

Comment: if nothing happens for half an hour or so it might truly got stuck; this might happen with certain hardware configurations ... best you edit you question and tell us what hardware you are using (model); if you don't know run the live-session (Try-Ubuntu) open a terminal and enter `sudo lshw -short`and copy the output

Comment: Included files as you said sasuke

Comment: okay so it is an HP Spectre x360 with Nvidia GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050M]

Comment: well I searched the web and it seems it has to do with the graphics card, so could you try the `save grafic mode` on boot - shortly after usb device boots there appears a grafic on the lower botoom half of the screen, depicting an keyboard and a human in a circle, as soon as you see it press any key and after selecting you language there are several boot options - select the one with safe praphics and try again to install

Comment: Problem solved, thanks for commenting, i had two uallocated partitions which i merged into my c drive.....which solves problem

Comment: would you mind writing up your solution as answer, so someone else might benefit from it ;)

Answer (score 0):

During the install process, this particular step can take a minute or two to finish loading, but if it's still going on, then I'd recommend you restart into the installation media, and make sure not to skip the filesystem check it performs at boot. The problem itself may be fixed by a reboot, but I suspect that there's something wrong with the installation media if it's taking that long. This check at boot should give that answer, and in the case that it detects an error in the disk, you'll have two options to run through.

The first is checking the downloaded ISO to ensure that it matches the md5 checksum posted on the download page. You can go about this a couple different ways. The first I will show you applies to Ubuntu, so you can do it if the iso is downloaded on a Linux machine, or by downloading the Ubuntu terminal from the Microsoft store in Windows (I recommend doing this if you plan on dual-booting, as it makes terminal commands equivalent between Windows and Ubuntu). First you'll need to navigate to the folder that you downloaded it to, which is likely "Downloads".

```
cd Downloads
```

Verifying the md5sum is pretty simple, and really just requires that you run the command below and check that the value returned is equal to the one that corresponds to the version of Ubuntu that you downloaded on [this page](https://releases.ubuntu.com/focal/MD5SUMS).

```
md5sum ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso
```

or if you downloaded the server version:

```
md5sum ubuntu-20.04-live-server-amd64.iso
```

The second method is doing it through a Windows terminal. To access one, just hit the Windows key + R and type cmd before hitting enter, right click on the start menu and click on command prompt, or search "cmd" in the search bar. You'll still have to navigate to the folder you downloaded the iso to in the terminal.

```
cd Downloads
```

You'll use the [same page](https://releases.ubuntu.com/focal/MD5SUMS) to verify the checksum, then run the following command.

```
certutil -hashfile ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso MD5
```

or if you downloaded the server version:

```
certutil -hashfile ubuntu-20.04-live-server-amd64.iso MD5
```

If those values do not match, then you will have to delete the iso, redownload it, and run the checksum again to make sure there wasn't another error in download. In the event that the values match, then you'll have to format your installation media and recreate it either through Rufus (Windows) or through dd (Linux). You should already know how to do this step since you'd already gotten that far. If that doesn't fix your problem, then I'm not entirely sure where to go from there, but I hope it fixes your issue!

Comment: After ruuning command it says....certutil: -hasfile command completed successfully

Comment: since 20.04 this check is built in and performed on boot

Comment: Thanks for commenting my problem solved